# customized list view for multiple screen support in android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, android-screen-support

In my app am using customized listed view with text view and Buttons.The screen size is 4.65" 720p(720X1280 : xhdpi),device take this resolution from layout-large folder.when i run it on device.the list view item and header display not fit to the screen,some empty space in the end of row.Its not able to fit to the screen.Can any one know please help me to solve this issue.

**Header XML Coding**

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="20dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/search_lay"
    android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
    android:background="#e8e8e8" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
        android:text="Item(s)"
        android:textColor="#dd1713"
        android:textSize="13sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="48dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView1"
        android:text="Price(Rs.)"
        android:textColor="#dd1713"
        android:textSize="13sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="18dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView3"
        android:text="Qty"
        android:textColor="#dd1713"
        android:textSize="13sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="28dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView2"
        android:text="Total(Rs.)"
        android:textColor="#dd1713"
        android:textSize="13sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
        android:text="Fav"
        android:textColor="#dd1713"
        android:textSize="13sp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**Customized List-view XML Coding**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="#ffffff" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/orderlist_product_id"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/fav_img"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:background="@drawable/fav_order_list_btn" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/special_inst_btn"
            android:layout_width="25dp"
            android:layout_height="18dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/fav_img"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:background="@drawable/special_inst_btn_in_orderlist"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="+"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="14sp" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/order_list_itemname"
        android:layout_width="95dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
        android:text="Item name"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:typeface="serif" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="34dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="2dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/orderlist_offer"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="#298616"
            android:textSize="10sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/orderlist_price"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:text="200.00"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="10sp"
            android:typeface="serif" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/orderlist_minus"
        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
        android:background="@drawable/sub_button_click" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/order_list_quantity"
        android:layout_width="27dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="13dp"
        android:background="@drawable/et_bg"
        android:ems="10"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="12dp"
        android:typeface="serif" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/orderlist_plus"
        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
        android:background="@drawable/plus_btn_click" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/orderlist_total"
        android:layout_width="43dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="13dp"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:text="1000.00"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="11sp"
        android:typeface="serif" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/orderlist_delete"
        android:layout_width="23dp"
        android:layout_height="23dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
        android:background="@drawable/order_list_delete" />
</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

For Different screen size, The following is a list of resource directories in an application that provides different layout designs for different screen sizes and different bitmap drawables for small, medium, high, and extra high density screens.

```
      res/layout/my_layout.xml             // layout for normal screen size ("default")
      res/layout-small/my_layout.xml       // layout for small screen size
      res/layout-large/my_layout.xml       // layout for large screen size
      res/layout-xlarge/my_layout.xml      // layout for extra large screen size              res/layout-xlarge-land/my_layout.xml // layout for extra large in landscape orientation

      res/drawable-mdpi/my_icon.png        // bitmap for medium density
      res/drawable-hdpi/my_icon.png        // bitmap for high density
      res/drawable-xhdpi/my_icon.png       // bitmap for extra high density
```

The following code in the Manifest supports all dpis.

```
<supports-screens android:smallScreens="true" 
  android:normalScreens="true" 
  android:largeScreens="true"
  android:xlargeScreens="true"
  android:anyDensity="true" />
```

Comment: Am put like that only its not fit for 720x1280 : xhdpi,All other resolutions it works perfectly.

Comment: that's means in xhdpi screen its not fit??

Comment: OK..You have implemented your custom header xml file in large folder accroding to your question but you should implement it in xlarge folder.

Comment: am use xlarge but for the 4.65" 720x1280 : xhdpi resolution it take from layout-large

Comment: have you add res/layout-xlarge/customizedHeader.xml??